# Postgres time comparaison with time zone

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone

Today I encounter a strange postgres behavious. Let me explain:

Here is my table I will work on.

```
=># \d planning_time_slot 
                                        Table "public.planning_time_slot"
   Column    |           Type            | Collation | Nullable |                    Default                     
-------------+---------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                   |           | not null | nextval('planning_time_slot_id_seq'::regclass)
 planning_id | integer                   |           | not null | 
 day         | character varying(255)    |           | not null | 
 start_time  | time(0) without time zone |           | not null | 
 end_time    | time(0) without time zone |           | not null | 
 day_id      | integer                   |           | not null | 0
Indexes:
    "planning_time_slot_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_a9e3f3493d865311" btree (planning_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_a9e3f3493d865311" FOREIGN KEY (planning_id) REFERENCES planning(id)
```

what i want to do is something like:

```
select * from planning_time_slot where start_time > (CURRENT_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris');
```

But it seems like postgres is comparing time before the time zone conversion.
Here is my tests:

```
=># select * from planning_time_slot where start_time > (CURRENT_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris');
 id  | planning_id | day | start_time | end_time | day_id 
-----+-------------+-----+------------+----------+--------
 157 |           6 | su  | 16:00:00   | 16:30:00 |      0
(1 row)
=># select (CURRENT_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris');
      timezone      
--------------------
 16:35:48.591002+02
(1 row)
```

When I try with a lot of entries it appears that the comparaison is done between start_time and CURRENT_TIME without the time zone cast.

For your information I also tried :

```
select * from planning_time_slot where start_time > timezone('Europe/Paris', CURRENT_TIME);
```

It has the exact same result.

I also tried to change the column type to **time(0) with time zone**. It makes the exact same result.

One last important point. I really need to set timezone I want, because later on I will change it dynamically depending on other stuffs. So it will not be 'Europe/Paris' everytime.

Does anyone have a clue or a hint please ?

*psql (PostgreSQL) 11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1)*

Comment: Use `localtime` instead of `current_time` and ditch the whole time zone stuff

Comment: What does `show timezone` return?

Comment: I cannot ditch the whole time zone stuff, since I will later change the timezone dynamically and not let it just be Eur/Paris.

Comment: show timezone returns:
```TimeZone  ----------  UCT (1 row)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(CURRENT_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris')` is, for example, `17:52:17.872082+02`. But internally it is `15:52:17.872082+00`. Both time and timetz (time with time zone) are all stored as UTC, the only difference is timetz is stored *with a time zone*. Changing the time zone does not change what point in time it represents.

So when you compare it with a time...

```
# select '17:00:00'::time < '17:52:17+02'::timetz;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

That is really...

```
# select '17:00:00'::time < '15:52:17'::time;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

Casting a timetz to a time will lop off the time zone.

```
test=# select (CURRENT_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris')::time;
    timezone     
-----------------
 17:55:57.099863
(1 row)

test=# select '17:00:00' < (CURRENT_TIME AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris')::time;
 ?column? 
----------
 t
```

Note that this sort of comparison only makes sense if you want to store the notion that a thing happens at 17:00 according to the clock on the wall. For example, if you had a mobile phone game where an event starts "at 17:00" meaning 17:00 where the user is. This is referred to as a "floating time zone".

---

- Assuming `day` is "day of week", I suggest storing it as an integer. It's easier to compare and localize.
- Instead of separate start and end times, consider a single [`timerange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/rangetypes.html). Then you can use [range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-range.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation ! It works very well when cast to a time.
Also, your idea of timerange is very good for my purpose, because I will probably need range operators later on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have deeper problems.

You have a day, a start time and an end time, but no notion of time zone. So this will mean something different depending on the time zone of the observer.

I think you should add a `tz` column that stores which time zone that information is in. Then you can get the start time like this:

```
WHERE (day + start_time) AT TIME ZONE tz > current_timestamp
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Indead I have a timezone column in another table (table planning). I will investigate your answer aswell with that in mind. It looks like a great idea